# Complex Roots in a Complex Equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> **Problem:** The equation $$\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{x}{x+2} = kx$$ has exactly two complex roots. Find all possible complex values for $k.$

---

**Progress:** I was online today, and I saw this problem. Heres what I tried: $$(x+1)x+(x+2)x=kx(x+1)(x+2),$$ and I immediately got stuck :(. I'm quite new at complex numbers. Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* A polynomial equation of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots (counted with multiplicity). The simplified expression has degree at most $3$. Therefore, it either has a double root or is of degree $2$ with simple roots. Note that $x=0$ is a root.

Comment: Make sure not to include $x=-1$ and $x=-2$ as roots because they cannot happen in the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

While @lhf has provided the right hint, some careful case work is needed, hence elaborating a bit.

First, one must note the denominators can't be zero, so the domain of $x$ does not contain $\{-1, -2\}$.  Given this, you can multiply by $(x+1)(x+2)$ to get your equation as
$$(x+1)x + (x+2)x = kx(x+1)(x+2)$$
$$\iff kx^3 + (3k-2)x^2+(2k-3)x=0$$

Clearly $x=0$ is a root.  If in all there are exactly two roots, and $a$ is the other root, then we could have the roots as $(0,0,a), (0, a, a), (0,a)$ (of course without considering ordering).

For $x=0$ to be a double root, it is evident $\color{red}{k=\frac32}$ must be true.  So this is one value for $k$, which is indeed a complex number. (*You should verify that this value indeed gives the last root in the allowable domain.*)

If $x=0$ is not a multiple root, then we have what remains after cancellation of $x$, viz. $kx^2+(3k-2)x+(2k-3)=0$ should have exactly one more root.  This can happen in two ways,:

EITHER

the quadratic $kx^2+(3k-2)x+(2k-3)=0$, has a double root.  Thus it's discriminant is zero, hence
$$(3k-2)^2-4k(2k-3)=0 \iff k^2+4=0$$
which gives $\color{red}{k=\pm2i}$, which are the only other possible values.  (*Once again you should verify this leads to roots for the quadratic which are allowable in the domain.*)

OR

we have essentially only one root, i.e. $\color{red}{k=0}$ so that what remains after cancellation is really $-2x-3=0 \implies x =-\frac32$.

Collecting all cases, the values possible are $\color{red}{k \in \{\frac32,2i, -2i, 0\}}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It took a whole day of thinking, but I actually solved it! You're answers are correct, by the way.

Comment: A very thorough, careful answer but apparently the first time through I did not **read** it carefully enough. All the solutions found are in agreement with the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Good!
Yes, multiplying both sides by $(x+ 1)(x+ 2)$ "reduces" the equation to $(x+ 1)x+ (x+ 2)x= kx(x+ 1)(x+ 2)$.  Now, I would do the indicated multiplications to get $x^2+ x+ x^2+ 2x= kX*(x^2+ 3x+ 2)= kx^3+ 3kx^2+ 2kx$ which can be written as $kx^3+ (3k- 1)x^2+ (2k- 1)x= 0$.  The left side can be factored as $x(kx^2+ (3k- 1)x+ (2k- 1))= 0$.  One root is $x= 0$ and, if $x$ is not $0$, $kx^2+ (3k- 1)x+ (2k-1)= 0$ can be solved by the "quadratic formula".

Comment: You don't need to solve the equation to count the roots.

Comment: @lhf Please explain?